# Apple Push Notification (remote) is not working when the screen is locked. Nothing is shown on Apple's notification tab too

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I push the notification, iPhone screen turns on (probably because the app is awaken.) However no notification is shown on lock screen or notification tab.

iOS notification is not working when screen is locked. Nothing is shown in Notification tab too. Banner is working fine when app is in background (screen unlocked) or foreground.

I use the following code to push notification using node-apn (I opened a ticket on the repo too: https://github.com/argon/node-apn/issues/418):

```
function pushNotificationToMany() {
    console.log("Sending the same notification each of the devices with one call to pushNotification.");
    var note = new apn.notification();
    note.setAlertTitle("Hello from my app");
    note.setAlertText("Hello, world!");
    note.setCategory("message");
    note.setContentAvailable(1);
    note.badge = 1;

    service.pushNotification(note, tokens);
}

pushNotificationToMany();
```

My iOS code in AppDelegate.m include the following functions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");
    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory* notificationCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    notificationCategory.identifier = @"message";
    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:notificationCategory, nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:categories]];
    NSDictionary *payload = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (payload)
        NSLog(@"payload is : %@", payload);
    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings // NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{

    NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as you need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"remote notification user info %@", userInfo);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler {
    NSLog(@"another remote notification user info %@", userInfo);
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        NSLog(@"Inactive");

        //Show the view with the content of the push

        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        NSLog(@"Background");

        //Refresh the local model

        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Active");

        //Show an in-app banner

        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    }
}
```

Comment: is there any php script you using to get notifications ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to add in UIMutableUserNotificationAction in order to get the results I want. The following code works:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction1.identifier = @"Accept";
    notificationAction1.title = @"Accept";
    notificationAction1.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    notificationAction1.destructive = NO;
    notificationAction1.authenticationRequired = NO;

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction2.identifier = @"Reject";
    notificationAction2.title = @"Reject";
    notificationAction2.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    notificationAction2.destructive = YES;
    notificationAction2.authenticationRequired = YES;

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *notificationAction3 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    notificationAction3.identifier = @"Reply";
    notificationAction3.title = @"Reply";
    notificationAction3.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
    notificationAction3.destructive = NO;
    notificationAction3.authenticationRequired = YES;

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *notificationCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    notificationCategory.identifier = @"Email";
    [notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2,notificationAction3] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    [notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:notificationCategory, nil];

    UIUserNotificationType notificationType = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationType categories:categories];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
//    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:categories]];
    NSDictionary *payload = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (payload)
        NSLog(@"payload is : %@", payload);
    return YES;
}
```